# Beamer theme Error

Tags: beamer, themes

I am a new user of LaTeX (TeXstudio). I am making a lecture presentation in TeXstudio. I want to make the same design of my presentation which is attached below.

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\batchmode
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,epsfig,bbm,calc,color,ifthen,capt-of}
\usetheme{Berlin}
 \usecolortheme{senac}
```

```
Error Massage : File `beamercolorthemesenac.sty' not found. \usecolortheme{senac}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Se! The color theme `senac` is not a standard option of the `beamer` class, but a specially designed template. You need to download those template files and put them in the same folder as your tex document.

Comment: You can find the missing file at https://www.overleaf.com/10070672jjshsgzwpshs#/37098200/

Comment: @Tiuri Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: The linked project above was edited and no longer worked. The original files are available from this template (which that project was created from originally): https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/beamer-template-for-senac-presentations/cwzzgzgfhrbm

Or you can get them directly from this read-only link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/chvppkrqsnqf

Answer (score 2):

As the error message tells you, the file `beamercolorthemesenac.sty` is missing. It is available from https://www.overleaf.com/10070672jjshsgzwpshs#/37098200/

Comment: The linked project was edited and no longer worked. The original files are available from this template (which that project was created from originally): https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/beamer-template-for-senac-presentations/cwzzgzgfhrbm

Or you can get them directly from this read-only link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/chvppkrqsnqf